# In my heatmap graphing component, the y-axis time text does not exactly align

Tags: c#, bitmap

I have a method that takes in a bitmap, width, height, and a list of strings, overlays it on top of a black background, and adds y-axis text onto it (as demonstrated in the picture below).

In my attempt to align the text so they occupy the exact vertical space of my graph, I took the height and divided it by the number of values in the list:

`float verticalDistance = height / times.Count;`

However, perhaps of alignment issues, the space between each time value on the y-axis doesn't fix exactly into the height of the original bitmap, which is the variable `height`.

I thought it was an issue with `int` and it rounding numbers up or down, but changing it `verticalDistance` to a float did not ameliorate the issue.

```
    private Bitmap overlayBitmap(Bitmap sourceBMP, int width, int height, List<String> times) {
        int newWidth = width + (width / 3);
        int newHeight = height + (height / 3);
        Bitmap result = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result)) {
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;

            StringFormat stringFormatX = new StringFormat();
            stringFormatX.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

            Font drawFontX = new Font("Whitney", 10);

            float verticalDistance = height / times.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < times.Count; i++) {
                if (i % 5 == 0) {
                    g.DrawString(times[i], drawFontX, Brushes.White, 5, ((newHeight - height)/2) + (verticalDistance * i), stringFormatX);
                }
            }
            g.DrawImage(sourceBMP, width / 6, height / 6, width, height);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

[image]

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce your problem to the simplest case: What if you had just two values to display on your Y axis? Your vertical distance would be the length of the axis. Your vertical distance formula would not work in that case. Therefore

```
float verticalDistance = height / (times.Count - 1.0);
```

Comment: Your solution, plus the fact that my floats were dividing by int, meant a loss of precision. As soon as I casted all my ints to floats, it worked perfectly. However - is this good practice? http://puu.sh/6ffT2/347fbcfc8a.png And the graph: http://puu.sh/6ffUa/9bca566850.png

Comment: I meant to say:

"The fact that my floats were dividing by int, meant a loss of precision. Your solution, plus me casting all my ints to floats, meant it worked perfectly. However - is this good practice?

Comment: I changed the 1 to 1.0 in my answer above, to force proper casting of the calculation terms. Is this good practice? It's the only way to ensure your verticalDistance is correct. If you want to avoid a division by zero error, you have to make sure that times.Count is always greater than 1.

Comment: I believe you would have to use `1.0f` as a float, but regardless, that's a smart casting. I have to remember this trick next time.

Comment: Any number with a decimal point in it will be considered floating point by the compiler, but 1.0 may be interpreted as either 1.0f or 1.0d (float or double), depending on your environment. In practice I find it doesn't matter, so I always omit the f or d suffix.